# Python: How can i use multiprocessing to speed up operating on class instances?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

for example:

```
instances = [ClassName() for i in range(no_inst)]
for data in dataset:
    for inst in instances:
        inst.dosomething(data)
```

Note: The instances do not modify the data, so there is no need of communication between the instances.

Comment: Which part of the `multiprocessing` documentation are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *easiest* way that I know of is to use [`multiprocessing.Pool.map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) the same way you would use the `map` builtin.  You just need to write a function to do the task that you want to complete and it handles all of the parallelism:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

instances = [ClassName() for i in range(no_inst)]

def dosomething(inst):
    for data in dataset:
        inst.dosomething(data)

num_procs = 4 #however many processors you'll use
pool = mp.Pool(num_procs)
pool.map(dosomething,instances)
```

there are a few gotchas -- `lambda` functions won't work here since they aren't pickleable for instance.  This also returns a list of `None` (since that is what `dosomething` returns) -- normally I don't like using list-comprehensions or `map` for side-effects, but I relax my stance on that when it comes to multiprocessing simply because it is *so easy*.

Comment: to make `dataset` available to the child processes, you could use Pool's `initializer` argument. If operations inside `inst.dosomething()` release GIL, you could use `ThreadPool` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- Maybe this is a result of always working on *NIX systems with `fork`, but I've never had to do that.  `dataset` has always gotten picked up from the closure just like a normal function.  Does it behave differently on Windows?

Comment: yes (no `fork` and the associated "copy-on-write" on Windows), you also need `if __name__ == "__main__"` to protect Pool creation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) interface to create a `Thread` class that fulfills the `dosomething(data)`. You can start multiple thread for each loop, calling `run()` to start them. It's recommended to then put them into a list so that you can check their status until all have completed.

Comment: On CPython this will run into the GIL and be no faster than serial processing.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: not necessarily true. Even with the GIL, multithreaded programs can be significantly faster than single-threaded ones. I/O-bound workloads are common.

Comment: There are some circumstances where threading has speedups compared to a serial implementation (even on Cpython).  However, those situations aren't all that common.